# How to delete a data in a many to many relationship table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

For example, i have 3 table which is supplier, supplier_product, and product.
1 supplier has many product and 1 product may supplied by many supplier, data stored in supplier_product table.

```
supplier1 - product2
supplier1 - product 1
```

i want to delete supplier 1 with product 1, how can i do it?

Table:

> Supplier | supplier_id, name.....
>
> Supplier_Product | supplier_id, product_id........
>
> Product | product_id, name.....

Comment: is your tables are already exist ? or can you drop that table and recreate ?

Comment: you need to drop foreign key constraint first. Without more info cannot answer. you need to provide even structure of tables

Comment: i don't think need to drop foreign key constraint first since i want to delete data in Supplier_product table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquents `detach()` or `sync()` methods which explanation you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)
Below are some examples

```
// detaching
$supplier = App\Supplier::find(1);
$supplier->products()->detach([1]);

// syncing
$supplier = App\Supplier::find(1);
$supplier->products()->sync([2]);
```

Comment: How does your code looks like at the moment? Do you mean the jQuery plugin [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)? @心心傷心

Comment: Yes, i am using jQuery datatable

Comment: Please edit your question and add some details AND show us your current codes @心心傷心